# Copy .csv files in to one file with file name printed to allinone.csv

Tags: copy, dos

I have been given a data extract dump from an Oracle DB (cc&b). Each extract comes with a .log file which gives a table def, pk, fk, data types etc. I want to copy all these files in to one. I aware of the MS-Dos command 
'copy *.log allinone.txt'
My problem is the content of the .log files do not contain the table name; the table name only exists on the file name. I need the table name printed in the allinone.txt file.
There are 486 tables so manual is not really ideal. Is there way to Print File Name + Content?

Comment: Do you mean Windows? or are you really using MS-DOS? (I doubt it) Your title says `.csv`, but your question text says `.log`. Which is it? Based on your description of the content, I imagine your files are not in csv format, and so probably do not have a `.csv` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are really using Windows, and not MS-DOS.

I'm also assuming all the `.log` files are in the same folder.

No batch file is required. Simply `CD` to the folder with the log files. Then run the following command:

```
type *.log >combinedLog.txt 2>&1
```

The TYPE command will include the file name at the top of each file output when a single command types multiple files. The file name is printed to stderr, so stderr is redirected to stdout (`2>&1`).

Comment: @NathanMacPherson - If you get an answer you are happy with that fully answers your question, then you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark in the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation points, and awards the answer poster 10 rep points. Only one answer per question can be accepted.